# TOMCAT 7 Access properties file outside WEB INF/classes

Tags: spring, tomcat

So i can access properties file if its in WEB-INF/classes. 
However if I keep the same file under TOMCAT/conf and updating catalina.properties to point to the path, I get an error like Name not bound.

I have almost tried everything...even tried with absolute path

Answer (score 0):

if your file.properties file is in the WEB-INF/classes folder? Then:?

```
 InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/file.properties");
```

Comment: I wanted to access it from outside the war not inside it\

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could solve it was
1. Create a env folder under tomcat_home and put the config.properties there
2. update catalina.properties and add the tomcat_home\env path in common loader
3. Comment out  from spring security XML

Once I commented the above line It ran fine.